# How to compare Object list with Long list in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying compare 2 lists , first list type is Long and second list Employee Object, and I want result set in a `Map<ID, Exists>` (`Map<Long, Boolean>`).

Note: first list has more Item from second list

```
List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee(2), new Employee(4), new Employee(6));
List<Long> ids = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L);
```

i need output

```
1 : false
2 : true
3 : false
4 : true
5 : false
6 : true
```

my code is:

```
resultMap = employees.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, ( 
                 anything -> 
                                 ids.contains(anything.getId() ) )));
for (Entry<Long, Boolean> entity : resultMap.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(entity.getKey() + " : " + entity.getValue());
}
```

but output is:

```
2 : true
4 : true
6 : true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set<Long> employeesId =repository.getByIds(ids).stream()
          .map(Employee::getId)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

then

```
Map<Long,Boolean> map =  ids.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(Function.identity(),id->employeesId.contains(id)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the first list has more elements than employees list, I think your logic is inverse, instead you have to check if each elements in ids exist in employees, to solve your issue, I think you need :

```
// store the employee ids in a list
Set<Long> empIds = employees.stream()
        .map(Employee::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// for each element in ids, check if it exist in empIds or not
Map<Long, Boolean> resultMap = ids.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> empIds.contains(e)));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ids.contains(anything.getId())` the problem is that you check that the employee's id is in the allId list, this will always be true for the employee ids you have, you may check in the other way

---

The best is collecting the employees id, then check if each id is in it or not

```
Set<Long> empIds = employees.stream().map(Employee::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
resultMap = ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), empIds::contains));
```

You could it in one line but it won't be efficient because you would stream on employees each time

```
resultMap = ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, 
                         id -> employees.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getId().equals(id))));
```

Answer (score 0):

i could write These codes

1.

```
resultMap = ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, id -> list.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getId().equals(id))));
```

2.

```
ids.forEach(id -> resultMap.put(id, list.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getId().equals(id))));
```